# Assetic file does not exist error, even though no reference to file anymore?

Tags: php, caching, assetic, symfony, symfony-console

I have a file called main.less that I created in the past.  I deleted it because I no longer needed it, but now I get the following error when I try to run `bin/console assetic:watch`

```
[error] The source file "/home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/bundles/app/less/main.less" does not exist.
```

or `bin/console assetic:dump` regardless of environment used.

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                                                                        
  The source file "/home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/bundles/app/less/main.less" does not exist.
```

My current routine which has been working until I did this was to create a shell script file that runs the following commands:

```
chown -R distribution:distribution .
rm -rf var/cache/dev/*
rm -rf var/cache/prod/*
rm -rf web/css/*
rm -rf web/js/*
bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
bin/console assets:install web --symlink --relative
bin/console assetic:dump --env=dev --verbose
bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
bin/console assetic:watch
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql --env=prod
chown -R distribution:distribution .
bin/console server:run
```

I always run it as root to ensure everything will work, files are owned by user distribution though.

The only file that references the less and javascript files is...

**base.html.twig**

```
{% spaceless %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets 'bundles/skeleton/less/main.less' filter='less' filter='uglifycss' filter='cssrewrite' output='css/compiled-main.css' %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
            {% endstylesheets %}
        {% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
            {% javascripts 
             '@SkeletonBundle/Resources/public/js/*' 
             '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
              filter='uglifyjs2' 
              output='js/js-compiled.js' 
            %}
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
                <script src="{{ asset_url }}"</script>
            {% endjavascripts %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
{% endspaceless %}
```

My Directory structure looks like below straight from my FTP

[image]

You will notice main.less is now in skeleton bundle instead of the app bundle.  I moved it here, but for some reason it thinks its still in app bundle instead of skeleton bundle??

**How do I fix this error?**

Extra Info:

When I ran a verbose trace of the error I got this with asset:dump

```
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is on.

03:37:43 [file+] /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/css/compiled-main.css
        /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/bundles/skeleton/less/main.less
03:37:43 [file+] /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/css/compiled-main_main_1.css
        /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/bundles/skeleton/less/main.less
03:37:44 [file+] /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/js/js-compiled.js
        /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/src/SkeletonBundle/Resources/public/js/shared.js
        /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/app.js
03:37:44 [file+] /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/js/js-compiled_part_1_shared_1.js
        /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/src/SkeletonBundle/Resources/public/js/shared.js
03:37:45 [file+] /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/js/js-compiled_part_2_app_1.js
        /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/app.js
03:37:45 [file+] /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/css/compiled-main.css
        /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/bundles/app/less/main.less


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                        
  The source file "/home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/app/../web/bundles/app/less/main.less" does not exist.  


Exception trace:
 () at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/FileAsset.php:62
 Assetic\Asset\FileAsset->load() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/BaseAsset.php:103
 Assetic\Asset\BaseAsset->dump() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Asset/AssetCollection.php:151
 Assetic\Asset\AssetCollection->dump() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Command/AbstractCommand.php:119
 Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\AbstractCommand->doDump() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Command/AbstractCommand.php:51
 Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\AbstractCommand->dumpAsset() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Command/DumpCommand.php:118
 Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\DumpCommand->execute() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:803
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:186
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:86
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/distribution/public_html/distribution.tech/bin/console:29

assetic:dump [--forks FORKS] [--watch] [--force] [--period PERIOD] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<write_to>]
```

**Config.yml assetic settings:**

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        uglifyjs2:
            # the path to the uglifyjs executable
            bin: /usr/bin/uglifyjs
        uglifycss:
            bin: /usr/bin/uglifycss
        less: 
            node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/]
            bin: /usr/bin/less
```

**Main.less in skeleton bundle**

```
/* Global Variables */
@logo: "../images/logo-hires-opt.png";

/* Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNova';
    src: url('../fonts/proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaAltBold';
    src: url('../fonts/proxima_nova_alt_bold-webfont.ttf');
}

.withfont{font-family:ProximaNova;color:blue;background:url('../images/background.jpg');}

@import "shared.less";
@import "header.less";
@import "footer.less";
```

**Admin.less file in appBundle**

```
.test{color:red}
```

**admin.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'SkeletonBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="withfont">admin page</div>
            <div>admin page without <span class="test">fonts</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out that my editor had an old version open to `base.html.twig` that was referencing the older location, so when it went to render it could not find it... I'm not sure how I didn't notice this, but the error was indeed related to the file not actually being there.

The error was in this command

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/skeleton/less/main.less' filter='less' filter='uglifycss' filter='cssrewrite' output='css/compiled-main.css' %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
            {% endstylesheets %}
```

weird part is I would have sworn I deleted the old base.html.twig, but after doing some tweaks it magically re-appeared, and I think it has to do with my editor and how it saves since I moved files around and kept the editor open at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

In my case was necessary clear cache...

`php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev`

i was search for this file name (as string) in whole project `ctrl+shift+f` in phpstorm and he found file somewhere in cache directory... Maybe if you delete line from cached file it will be enough... but clear all cache i my case 100% success